# Google builds incorrect sitelinks for menu anchors with the description — how to prevent that?

Tags: sitelinks

We currently have the following structure of the menu anchor:

```
<a href="/">Page<span>A description for the page in mega menu</span></a>
```

The problem that Google than build sitelinks incorrectly, showing and cutting the description right immediately after the page title. 
e.g.

Main result link

Page 1A description for...
Page 2A description for...

So do we need to pull out  from anchors or is there a way to solve that without changing the structure?

Comment: Is the problem just the lack of space?   Would "Page 1 description for" be acceptable?

Comment: The main problem is that Google doesn't separate link and description in the sitelinks (as I guess it thinks it's a single link).

Comment: Could you move the description outside of the anchor? You might try added title attributes to the anchors which match the page title of the destination in the sitemap.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins yes I can — but that would require some additional js work I think to make the whole block clickable.